# How can I fetch only files which can contains 'test' word in practice.txt file and merging data into

Tags: regex, linux

cat practice.txt
test_0909_3434 test_8838 test_case_5656_5433 case_4333_3211 note_4433_2212

practice.txt file contains some more files.
required output:

> test_0909_3434 test_8838

These test files contain some data so that I need to merge these two files data into one final file.

test_0909_3434 file contains:

> id    name
>
> 1     hh
>
> 2     ii

test_8838 file contains:

> id    name
>
> 2     ii
>
> 3     gg
>
> 4     kk

Final Output of output file: mergedfile.txt will be like follows:

> id    name
>
> 1     hh
>
> 2     ii
>
> 3     gg
>
> 4     kk

we need to remove redundant data also like above mergedfile.txt

Comment: Perl, sed, awk, shell, Python. Your choice. Give it a try and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

1) simplistic (data is "in-order" and "well-formatted" in both input files):

cat f1 f2 | sort -u > f3

2) more complex (not "in-order" and not "well-formatted"). use regex.

Read records from both input files. Assume input record is called 'x'.

```
if [[ "${x}" =~ ^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*)$ ]]; then
    d="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    s="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    echo "d == $d, s == $s"
fi

aa["${d}"]="${k}"
```

Where aa is a Bash associative array (available in Bash >= 4x).

declare -A aa=()

This assumes the the first field is an integer (and a key). You can process accordingly, as to whether or not the key is unique.

If it's any more complex than this, consider using Perl.